# Google speech to text, audio from browser to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary, google-speech-api

I want to convert my audio stream to text, right now i am doing :

```
server.on('connection', function (client) {
  console.log("new connection...");
  var fileWriter = null;
  var writeStream = null;

  client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {

    const request = {
      config: {
        encoding: 'LINEAR16',
        sampleRateHertz: meta.sampleRate,
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
      interimResults: false, //Get interim results from stream
    };
    const recognizeStream = speechClient
      .streamingRecognize(request)
      .on('error', error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .on('data', data =>
        console.log(data)
      );
    // fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter("demo.wav", {
    //   channels: 1,
    //   sampleRate: meta.sampleRate,
    //   bitDepth: 16 });
    stream.pipe(recognizeStream);

  });


});
```

when i convert it into "WAV" file it works but not working withrecognizeStream   for google. I am using Binaryjs.